# Named Positional Arguments in Cobra

Tags: go, cobra

I have the following [Cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra) sub-command:

```golang
package stripeCommands

import (
    "fmt"
    "cmd/cliConstants"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
    "log"
)

var (
    deleteCustomerCommand = &cobra.Command{
        Use:        "delete",
        Short:      "Delete Stripe customer(s) by ids.",
        Args:       cobra.MinimumNArgs(1),
        ArgAliases: []string{"stripe_customer_id"},
        PreRun: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {

        },
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            log.Printf("IDs: %v", args)
        },
    }
)

func init() {
    flags := deleteCustomerCommand.Flags()

    // -k|--stripe-api-key|STRIPE_API_KEY
    flags.StringP(cliConstants.CLIFlagStripeAPIKey, "k", "",
        fmt.Sprintf("The Stripe API key. [env: %s]", cliConstants.EnvVarStripeAPIKey))
}
```

The idea is to call this via `./my-app stripe customers delete -k $STRIPE_API_KEY $CUSTOMER_ID_1 $CUSTOMER_ID_2`.

While `cobra.MinimumNArgs(1)` does ensure I get at least one positional argument, I can't find a way to make this show up in the help documentation:

```
Error: requires at least 1 arg(s), only received 0
Usage:
  my-app stripe customers delete [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help                    help for delete
  -k, --stripe-api-key string   The Stripe API key. [env: stripe_api_key]

2021/09/13 12:00:39 Failed to execute command: requires at least 1 arg(s), only received 0
```

Is there a way to tell Cobra to display positional args in the help like:

```
Usage:
  my-app stripe customers delete [flags] customer_id [...customer_id]
```

Right now the help documentation is not very helpful in displaying to the user what they should pass as positional arguments.

Comment: You might consider `cmd.Example` for this.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `Use` field for your command to :

```
    deleteCustomerCommand = &cobra.Command{
        Use: "delete [flags] customer_id [...customer_id]",
        ...
```

The complete details of how it is used can be found in the code for [`cmd.UseLine()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/cobra#Command.UseLine) :
https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/v1.2.1/command.go#L1245